# Как более грамотно составить ООП для программы по типу "корзина"?

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть приблизительная задача:

> 1. Реализовать корзину товаров со следующей функциональностью:
>
>    - Добавление товара в корзину
>    - Удаление товара из корзины
>    - Изменение количества товара в корзине
>    - Применение купона к товару
>    - Применение купона к корзине
>    - Undo
>    - Redo
>    - Печать чека
> 2. Купон одного типа может быть применен:
>
>    - Либо только к товару.
>    - Либо только к корзине.
>    - В зависимости от применения купона меняется скидка.

Как на примере этой задачи можно составить грамотную логику ООП? Т.е. приблизительно с чего начать, от чего оттолкнуться?

Comment: По всей видимости сложный вопрос...

Comment: В первую очередь составить доменную модель - список сущностей, которые используются в программе и их аттрибуты: пользователь(если нужен), корзина, товар, чек, купон, etc (это model). Дальше отобрать функциональность: выбор товаров, отображение корзины, отображение купонов (это будет view-model). Дальше по обстоятельствам смотреть.

Comment: @AlexKrass спасибо, идея хороша, но многое не нужно, достаточно сделать корзину с товаром и выбором его, а дальше отправкой на печать. Т.е. ничего усложнять не нужно.

Comment: «Т.е. ничего усложнять не нужно» — ну так тогда и ООП не нужно, делайте всё в одном классе.

Comment: @VladD по шапке за это надавали, сказали надо разделить... :) вот и мучаюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Класс "Менеджер"**

Свойства:

- Список<"Корзина">

Методы

- Undo (выбирает нужную по порядку корзину из списка)
- Redo (выбирает нужную по порядку корзину из списка или последнюю)
- Добавление товара в корзину (создание новой Корзины в список и в ней соответствующий метод)
- Удаление товара из корзины (создание новой Корзины в список и в ней соответствующий метод)
- Изменение количества товара в корзине (создание новой Корзины в список и в ней соответствующий метод)
- Применение купона к корзине (создание новой Корзины в список и в ней соответствующий метод)
- Печать чека (по текущей корзине)

**2. Класс "Корзина"**

Свойства:

- Список<"Товар">
- Список<"Купон">

Методы

- Добавление товара в корзину
- Удаление товара из корзины
- Изменение количества товара в корзине (соответствующий метод товара)
- Применение купона к корзине (в список купонов)
- Расчет цены
- Конструктор - на вход должен принимать объект "Корзина" и копировать все его свойства. При пустой входящей корзине - просто корзина с пустыми списками.

**3. Класс "Товар"**

Свойства

- Ссылка на ТоварОписание
- Количество
- Список<"Купон">

Методы

- Изменение количества товара в корзине
- Применение купона к товару (в список купонов)
- Расчет суммы

**4. Класс Абстрактный "Купон"**

Свойства:

- Процент скидки
- Сумма скидки

Методы:

- Применить
- Фабрика - в зависимости от типа на входе создает экземпляр нужного потомка для Товара или Корзины

**5. Класс "Купон для товара" наследник от класса "Купон"**

Свойства:

- Товар

Методы:

- Применить

**6. Класс "Купон для корзины" наследник от класса "Купон"**

Свойства:

- Корзина

Методы:

- Применить

**7. Класс "ТоварОписание"**

Свойства

- Всякая хрень
- Цена